# Facebooks's expirationDate is 0

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I just realised that I don't get any more information about the expiration date of the access token. Precisely I'm talking about the facebook SDK for android where I call the `authorize()` method with a `DialogListener` callback as shown in the code below.

I haven't looked at it for some weeks btu I know it was working before, now as I return to the project I find the call of `facebook.getAccessExpires()` returning 0 every time.

My first thought was the API might be broken and some changes applied I didn't noticed. However using an iPhone project of about same age it seems to receive an expiration date. (From what I can see with my lack of objective-c skills ^^).

Next I checked out commit `5a72863793521a96f5a9f4fb72960a27b98e441d` from [facebook's github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master) 'cause I started to implemented supporting FB around this time and thought this way I might see if the SDK changed in some dramatic way.

So far all my efforts been in vain and I can't think of a good reason where to track down this bug.

```
DialogListener dialogListener = new DialogListener(){
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        mPrefsEdit.putString(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken() )
                  .putLong(USER_ACCESS_EXPIR, facebook.getAccessExpires() )
                  .commit();
        }
   //other required overrides
}

Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);    
facebook.authorize(activity, APP_PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, dialogListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook stop providing access of `offline access token permission`. So access token will valid for very sort time (2-8 hour).  See [facebook blog](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) for more details.

This the main reason `facebook.getAccessExpires()` always return 0.

Comment: Sweet! Not the fact I've got more stuff to think about but the fast and clear answer. Thanks for the link! :)